# How To Generate the Data for missing Dates till current date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a use case, where the data/orders from source comes everyday also may not on few days.
I want to generate the data for all the dates till today as below

| Sales | Order_Qunty | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 20000 | 20231202 |
| 30 | 30000 | 20231205 |
| 30 | 40000 | 20231207 |

Expected Output

| Sales | Order_Qunty | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 20000 | 20231202 |
| 0 | 0000 | 20231203 |
| 0 | 0000 | 20231204 |
| 30 | 30000 | 20231205 |
| 0 | 0000 | 20231206 |
| 30 | 40000 | 20231207 |
| 0 | 0000 | 20231208 |
| 0 | 0000 | 20231209 |
| 0 | 0000 | 20231210 |
| 0 | 0000 | 20231211 |
| 0 | 0000 | 20231212 |

I want to Generate the data for each date till today using the above source table and the Date table which has the date range from 19000101 - 20991231
Please Advise

Thanks in advance

Comment: which version of sql server you are using ?

Comment: something like: `select isnull(s.sales, 0) as sales, isnull(s.order_qunty, 0) as order_qty, c.date from calender c left join sales s on s.date = c.date` perhaps?

Comment: If you have the dates table, what is your issue, just doing a simple left join?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` between the Date table and the source table. This will fill in missing dates with zeros for `Sales` and `Order_Quantity`.

```
SELECT COALESCE(S.Sales, 0) AS Sales, COALESCE(S.Order_Qunty, '0000') AS Order_Qunty, D.Date
FROM DateTable D
LEFT JOIN SourceTable S ON D.Date = S.Date
WHERE D.Date BETWEEN '20230101' AND '20231212' -- Date range from the SourceTable
ORDER BY D.Date;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is implementation of PostgreSQL.

```
WITH date_sequence AS (
    SELECT generate_series(
        (SELECT MIN(date_column) FROM your_existing_data), 
        CURRENT_DATE, 
        '1 day'::interval
    )::DATE AS date_column
)
SELECT COALESCE(your_existing_data.Sales, 0) AS Sales, COALESCE(your_existing_data.Order_Qunty, '0000') AS Order_Qunty, ds.date_column
FROM date_sequence ds
LEFT JOIN your_existing_data ON ds.date_column = your_existing_data.date_column
ORDER BY ds.date_column;
```

In SqlServer

```
WITH DateSequence AS (
    SELECT MIN(date_column) AS date_column
    FROM your_existing_data
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, date_column)
    FROM DateSequence
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, date_column) <= GETDATE()
)
SELECT COALESCE(your_existing_data.Sales, 0) AS Sales, COALESCE(your_existing_data.Order_Qunty, '0000') AS Order_Qunty, ds.date_column
FROM DateSequence ds
LEFT JOIN your_existing_data ON ds.date_column = your_existing_data.date_column
ORDER BY ds.date_column;
```

Please replace your_existing_data to your real table name.

Comment: Which won't work on SQL Server. Postgresql specific `::` syntax for cast isn't supported. And other date/time functionality too.

Comment: Okay. I added sqlserver query on above answer.

Comment: I think you add more information in your post.
Expected Output